# java - What's the difference between (obj != null) and !(obj == null) in an condition?

Tags: java

I have the following question, for Java programmers.

Does there be any difference between setting `(obj != null)` rather than `!(obj == null)`?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: nooooo.

Comment: `!(obj == null)` is harder to read than `(obj != null)`. The former is a bit yoda-esque.

Comment: Is there any difference between `true` and `!false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [JLS Sec 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> At run time, the result of `==` is `true` if the operand values are both `null` or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is `false`.
>
> The result of `!=` is `false` if the operand values are both `null` or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is `true`.

And [JLS Sec 15.15.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6), which describes the logical complement operator (`!`):

> At run time, the operand is subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) if necessary. The value of the unary logical complement expression is `true` if the (possibly converted) operand value is `false`, and `false` if the (possibly converted) operand value is `true`.

So the two are exactly the same from an evaluation point of view; but `!=` is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any difference.
'Not equal to' (`!=`) is the sam as *not be* 'Equal to'.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference here, the !(obj==null) is just the another way for writing (reverse), and it also hard to understand than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any difference. `(obj != null)` is easier to read for most people.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** difference.
Also, some prefer having `null` close to each other while making a conditional check.

```
if(obj1 == null || null == obj2) // looks better to read
...

if(obj1 == null && obj.method()) // have high chances to throw an exception 
  even if True  && this will be checked

if(obj1 == null || obj.method()) // is preferred over the above one
    if True     || this will be NOT be checked
```